# Batch class to count record

Tags: apex

Below is my class which i am using to count number of record, But i am running this class on Visual force page, so this will update field only when i open record. So now i want to do batch class for this, so it will automatically run this query on every company record and update field.

I am new to batch class, Any one please help with how can i create batch class for this?

```
 public class Count{


    public integer i { get; set; }
    public integer j { get; set; }
    public integer k { get; set; }
    public integer l { get; set; }
    public integer Hit_rate { get; set; }
    public string s1;
    public integer Accepted_Hit_rate { get; set; }
    public integer package_Accepted_Hit_rate { get; set; }
    public Count(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


        s1=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('stop');


        }


    public PageReference vb(){

       i = [select count() from package__c where company__C=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

       j = [select count() from REOHQ__REOHQ_Offer__c   where company__C=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

       k = [select count() from REOHQ__REOHQ_Closing__c where company__C=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

       l =[select count() from REOHQ__REOHQ_Offer__c   where company__C=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') AND REOHQ__REOHQ_Offer_Status__c = 'Accepted'];

    REOHQ__REOHQ_Company__c op=[select Offer_count__c,Package_coun__c,Closing_count__c from REOHQ__REOHQ_Company__c where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

        op.Offer_count__c=j;
        op.Package_coun__c=i;
        op.Closing_count__c=k;
        op.Accepted_offer_count__c=l;


    update op;
    if(s1 != 'yes'){
    PageReference n=new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')+'?stop=yes');
    n.setredirect(true);

    return n;
    }
    return null;
    }   

        public Count() {


       }



     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really, you just have to "bulkify" your code and move some filters around, and you come up with:

```
public class BatchCount implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM REOHQ__REOHQ_Company__c]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, REOHQ__REOHQ_Company__c[] records) {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> packageCount = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
            [SELECT COUNT(Id) Sum, Company__c Id FROM Package__c WHERE Company__c IN :records GROUP BY Company__c]
        );
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> offerCount = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
            [SELECT COUNT(Id) Sum, Company__c Id FROM REOHQ__REOHQ_Offer__c WHERE Company__c IN :records GROUP BY Company__c]
        );
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> closingCount = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
            [SELECT COUNT(Id) Sum, Company__c Id FROM REOHQ__REOHQ_Closing__c WHERE Company__c IN :records GROUP BY Company__c]
        );
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> acceptedOfferCount = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
            [SELECT COUNT(Id) Sum, Company__c Id FROM REOHQ__REOHQ_Offer__c WHERE Company__c IN :records AND REOHQ__REOHQ_Offer_Status__c = 'Accepted' GROUP BY Company__c]
        );
        for(REOHQ__REOHQ_Company__c record: records) {
            record.Offer_Count__c = offerCount.containsKey(record.Id)?(Decimal)offerCount.get(record.Id).get('Sum'):0;
            record.Package_Count__c = packageCount.containsKey(record.Id)?(Decimal)packageCount.get(record.Id).get('Sum'):0;
            record.Closing_Count__c = closingCount.containsKey(record.Id)?(Decimal)closingCount.get(record.Id).get('Sum'):0;
            record.Accepted_Offer_Count__c = acceptedOfferCount.containsKey(record.Id)?(Decimal)acceptedOfferCount.get(record.Id).get('Sum'):0;
        }
        update records;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

Note: I'm not able to test this code, so you may need to do some minor tweaking. However, this should get you most of the way without too much effort.

Edit: Found I had my "casts" in the wrong place. Updated code.